# Sass not compiling in textmate

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use SASS for the first time with textmate. I seem to have installed it correctly by following the instructions on the git page - https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle 
but I can't find any information on how I can now use it.

When I make a .sass file the new Sass syntax is highlighted but when I save it is not compiled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to open up Terminal and in the command line, navigate to your project folder and run this command:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Name your working file `style.scss`, and it will compile and generate and update the `style.css` file that you reference in your document head.

Also make sure you have installed the Sass gem within your project directory :)

```
gem install sass
```

**UPDATE**

The bundle is only for installing syntax highlighting in Textmate. Sass is a precompiler for CSS, so it generates CSS from what you write in Sass. This is done through the `sass --watch` command above in the command line.

[Read more on how to use and install Sass.](http://sass-lang.com/)